# Calling a Function from the main Module in a Submodule in Go

Tags: go

Is there a way to call a function from the main module in a sub module?

I have a primary module with a submodule, such that my go.work is

```golang
go 1.19

use ./
use ./db
```

I would like to call a function from main, such as

```golang
package db

import "main"

func DatabaseCall() {
    main.FooBar("lorem")
}
```

I have tried reworking my module structure to

```golang
go 1.19

use ./main
use ./db
```

but I was still unable to call it. Is there something special about main, or am I just doing something wrong?

I have been able to pass the full function as a handler by redefining it like this:

```golang
// db
type FooBar func(ipsum string)

func DatabaseCall(handler FooBar) {
    handler("lorem")
}

// main
db.DatabaseCall(db.FooBar(FooBar))
```

but unless I am mistaken this means the entire function is copied in memory, which is not something I would want to do. You can pass it as a pointer, but must dereference it before calling which would copy it regardless.

Comment: You cannot import a main package.

Comment: You basically have two kinds of packages: library packages, which other packages can import; and main packages, which produce executables and cannot be imported.

Comment: You also cannot have circular dependencies, so even if this weren’t `main` you still cannot use packages in this way.

Comment: There is no such thing like a "submodule". All modules are equal.

Comment: _”unless I am mistaken this means the entire function is copied in memory”_, you are mistaken, because that is not how functions work. You appear to optimizing for a non-existant problem.